# Errors while building vanilla kernel for Android 

Tags: android, linux-kernel, android-source

I'm trying to build current (from git) vanilla Linux kernel for Android (Nexus S), I do following:

```
$ adb pull /proc/config.gz
$ cat config.gz | gunzip > .config
$ export PATH=$PATH:<...>/prebuilt/linux-x86/toolchain/arm-eabi-4.3.1/bin
$ export CROSS_COMPILE=arm-eabi-
$ make
```

After that I let all new options be default.
And I'm getting the following errors:

```
  CC      arch/arm/mach-s5pv210/common.o
arch/arm/mach-s5pv210/common.c:169: error: expected identifier or '(' before 'void'
arch/arm/mach-s5pv210/common.c:169: error: expected ')' before numeric constant
arch/arm/mach-s5pv210/common.c:201: error: expected identifier or '(' before 'void'
arch/arm/mach-s5pv210/common.c:201: error: expected ')' before numeric constant
arch/arm/mach-s5pv210/common.c:239: error: expected identifier or '(' before 'void'
arch/arm/mach-s5pv210/common.c:239: error: expected ')' before numeric constant
arch/arm/mach-s5pv210/common.c:247: error: expected identifier or '(' before 'void'
arch/arm/mach-s5pv210/common.c:247: error: expected ')' before numeric constant
make[1]: *** [arch/arm/mach-s5pv210/common.o] Error 1
make: *** [arch/arm/mach-s5pv210] Error 2
```

That's that line:

```
...
}

void __init s5pv210_map_io(void)
{
...
```

How to fix it? I didn't change anything in the source code

Comment: Can't promise it's relevant and there may well be other issues, but gcc 4.3.x strikes me as a bit old.  I think most Android work is now done on 4.4.x or even newer.  You should be able to adb shell 'cat /proc/version' to see what was used for the current kernel.

Comment: Linux version 3.0.29-Cyanogenmod-g7f075f6 (rankor@rankor-nettop) (gcc version 4.4.3 (GCC) ), compiled by me with this compiler.

Comment: Trying with 4.4.3, have the same error.

Comment: Assuming you cleaned before re-trying with 4.4.3, three ideas: rebuild the old kernel just to validate your methodology, diff the new and old kernel sources, re-check cynogen's kernel-building instructions.

Answer (score 1):

https://patchwork.kernel.org/patch/1940951/

this website will help you probably. ^^